# How to get dynamic array elements from multidimensional array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Input Data:**

```
[
  {
    'id': 10,
    'name': 'kohli',
    'email': 'kohli@email.com',
    'phone': '8080808080'
  },
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'john',
    'email': 'john@email.com',
    'phone': '987679090'
  }
]
```

I want to fetch particular elements using above multidimensional array, but need to call dynamically.

**Example:-**

```
function getDataFromArray(Params){
  // login here
}
```

**1. getDataFromArray(['id','name']) =>**

```
  [
      {
        'id': 10,
        'name': 'kohli'
      },
      {
        'id': 11,
        'name': 'john'
      }
    ]
```

In this example we want to fetch only id & name.

**2. getDataFromArray(['name','email']) =>**

```
  [
      {
        'name': 'kohli',
        'email': 'kohli@email.com'
      },
      {
        'name': 'john',
        'email': 'john@email.com'
      }
    ]
```

In this example we want to fetch name & email only.

So can we manage this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straight forward map / reduce operation

```js
const arr = [
  {
    'id': 10,
    'name': 'kohli',
    'email': 'kohli@email.com',
    'phone': '8080808080'
  },
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'john',
    'email': 'john@email.com',
    'phone': '987679090'
  }
]

function getDataFromArray(params) {
  return arr.map(item => params.reduce((o, param) => ({
    ...o,
    [ param ]: item[param]
  }), {}))
}

console.log("['id','name'] =>", getDataFromArray(['id','name']))
console.log("['name','email'] =>", getDataFromArray(['name', 'email']))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important;}
```

This *maps* each entry in the array to a new object that is constructed by *reducing* `params` to an object with keys from `params` and values from the objects in the array.